# how to access CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE with android opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

i am creating android app which it will detect faces but now i have got issue now that when i try to implement **detectMulitscale** Method to detect faces it shows error in CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE how to access it in android

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, face, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,new Size(30, 30),new Size());`
```

Comment: but what is the error?????

Comment: i cant not Access that

Comment: can you post what are you importing as libs?

Comment: i am importing x86

Answer (score 1):

you can use Objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE Instead of that

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, face, 1.1, 2, 0|Objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,new Size(30, 30),new Size());
```

hey check out this [tutorial](https://www.embedded-vision.com/forums/2013/01/14/using-face-detection-opencv-java-api) it did same face detection

Comment: wait am going to check it.

Comment: Thanks this tutorial did same thing thanks for help.